# why should we define the variables twice for a variable in objective c header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The following is the code from Apple docs. I dont really understand why a variable should be declared twice. Please see the below code. varaible 'passwordItem' has been declared twice. I understand the one with @property - it has the visibility to the outside classes. but why should it be declared under @interface also?

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;
DetailViewController *detailViewController;
KeychainItemWrapper *passwordItem;
KeychainItemWrapper *accountNumberItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) KeychainItemWrapper *passwordItem;
```

Comment: you don't need to do it like this. just `define` your `variables` in you `.h` file and `synthesise` those in you `.m` file. then it will setup `setters` and `getters` to your `variables`. above method used to do the same but very old.

Comment: The second declaration is not a duplicate variable, it is a property (ie getter & setter functions) and its associated memory management policy.